# Dynamic use of MDX AVG function

Tags: mdx, average

Anyone have advice on how to build an average measure that is dynamic -- it doesn't specify a particular slice but instead uses your current view? I'm working within a front-end OLAP viewer (Strategy Companion) and I need a "dynamic" implementation based on the dimensions that are currently filtered in the data view.

My fact table looks something like this:

```
Key AmountA  IndicatorA  AmountB  Other Data
1   5        1           null     25
2   6        1           null     52
3   7        1           2        106
4   null     0           4        108
```

Now I can specify a simple average for "[Measures].[AmountA]" with "[Measures].[AmountA] / [Measures].[IndicatorA]" which works great - "[IndicatorA]" sums up to the number of non-null values of "[AmountA]". And this also works great no matter what dimensions are selected in the view - it always divides by the count of rows that have been filtered in.

But what about [AmountB]? I don't have a null indicator column. I want to get an average value of [AmountB] for whatever rows have been filtered in for my current view. If I try to use the count of rows as a simple formula (psuedo-code "[Measures].[AmountB] / Count([Measures].[Key])") I get the wrong result, because it is counting all the null rows in the average.

So, I need a way to use the AVG function to specify the average of [AmountB] over the set of "whatever rows I'm currently filtering in, based on whatever dimensions I'm currently using".  How do I specify this dynamic set?

I've tried several different uses of the AVG function and they have either returned null or summed up to huge numbers, clearly not the average I'm looking for.

Thanks-
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my first suggestion was wrong. If you don't have access to OLAP cube you can't write any mdx-query for this purpose (IMHO). Because, you don't have any detailed data (from your fact table) in this access level and you can use only aggregated data and dimensions from your cube.
Otherwise (if you have access to olap db), you can create this metric (count of not NULL rows) in your measure group and after that use it for AVG calculation (as calculated member in your cube or in section "WITH" in your mdx-query).

Comment: Max, that's close - what I'm looking for now is how to specify {Your Set} as a dynamic set - not any particular slice but whatever set I'm currently filtering in with the OLAP tool.

Comment: I'll be able try to improve this query and update the answer in the nearest future.